# Spring MVC can @RequestMapping annotation be used to match url based on httpsession parameters

Tags: spring, attributes, mapping, overriding

I need to map @RequestMapping to two different controller methods based on http session attributes.

I see that @RequestMapping matches based on value, method, param and headers.
Is there a way to map based on session attribute?

If I use param, I need to force client to send request param
e.g.: aVersion=1 or aVersion=2.

If there is any example to override @RequestMapping? Can you point me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can add a `HttpSession` parameter to a your method in your controller. From the [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods):

> Session object (Servlet API): of type HttpSession. An argument of this type enforces the presence of a corresponding session. As a consequence, such an argument is never null.

However, you must do the session attribute check manually afaik:

```
@RequestMapping("/some_url")
void someMethod(HttpSession session) {

    Object firstAttr = session.getAttribute("firstAttribute");
    if (firstAttr != null) {
        doSomethingWithFirstAttribute(firstAttr);
    }

    Object secondAttr = session.getAttribute("secondAttribute");
    if (secondAttr != null) {
        doSomethingWithSecondAttribute(secondAttr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I was looking for is to deserialize @RequestBody based on session attribute. I can not do that in the suggested solution. I tried to extend RequestMapping, but then was unable to plugin that configuration. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The [@RequestBody](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) annotation maps the body of the request to a method parameter, so I don't think that will work for your example. However, you can create a method that includes both the body and the session as parameters:  
`@RequestMapping("/some_url")
void someMethod(@RequestBody String body, HttpSession session) {  
    // do stuff  
}`